# Chrome app webview transparent background

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am trying with no luck to create webview with transparent background.

Any chance to achieve that?

I have tried to set style to the webview element style="background:transparent;",
Also maked sure that the body of the website loaded in the webview is also transparent.

Comment: Would be more meaningful if you show how you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#allowtransparency) can sometimes be helpful. Not reading the docs is unhelpful in all cases.

> **allowtransparency**
>
> ```
> <webview id="foo"
>            src="http://www.google.com/"
>            style="width:640px; height:480px"
>            allowtransparency="on">
> </webview>
> ```
>
> If "on", transparent elements within the webview will be shown as transparent. Without `allowtransparency` enabled, there will be no transparency within the webview, even if elements exist that are specified as transparent.

Comment: I tried it, event before you asked, Its not mkae the webview trasparent. It only allow transparent elements within the webview.

Comment: Er, the webview itself? No, you cannot make the Chrome App window transparent, at least not in this way.

Comment: Any Idea how? or if its not possible? Coulden't find any reference in the documentation.